# Model: Standalone or "shadow copy" - is my relationship the best I could go with?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'd like to get your thoughts on my current problem.

I got a model called `Product` this product belongs to a category and has some information like tags, attributes, etc.

Now other models like `Invoice` or `Order` can make use of `Positions`. And each position relates to a product.

The important thing: This position-bound-product is a copy of the original `Product`-model and all of it's relations (this is very important: If the original product changes, the products linked to a position must not change).

So:

- `Product`: Describes product ("Standalone")
- `Position`: Describes positions attached to offers, orders or invoices. A position has a related product, that is a copy of a original product. This copy may not be shown on the index-page of products.

Now I try to figure out what's the best way to handle this.

At the moment I am doing this:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use App\Traits\FieldTrait;

/**
 * Class Product
 *
 * @package App
 */
class Product extends Model
{
    /**
     * @param $query
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function scopeWithoutShadowCopies($query): mixed
    {
        return $query->where('position_id', null);
    }

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function position(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Position::class);
    }

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }
}
```

This way I can add products that are "just" products and I can add products, that belong to a position. These products can be hidden by using `Product::withoutShadowCopies()->get()`.

This allows me to create a `Position` and create a "shadow copy" of the model `Product` without showing those  copies on my "Product list view".

What do you think? Is there a better way to get this working?